# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'DavidDaDon.png'

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Not really sure what I am doing wrong here. I have the the pngs in my src folder, I have used require and the relative path to the PNG. I feel like I am going crazy,  for reference. I am making a birthday reminder countdown with closest friends and family. The pics will end up being an accordian with their respective birthdays countdown. On countdown a text box will appear to call them. Also made an Accordian component that house the working code. Maybe I double imported? I have imports in the accordian file and in my app.js file.

```
import Accordian from './accordian';
import AugustusDaGreat from './AugustusDaGreat.png';
import DadMatt from './Dad-Matt.png';
 import DavidDaDon from 'DavidDaDon.png';
 import propic from './propic.png';
 import RickyKyle from './RickyKyle.png';
 
// import 5 pngs of friends
const gus = AugustusDaGreat;
  const dadMatt = DadMatt;
  const daveDaDon = DavidDaDon;
  const profilePic = propic;
  const bigDickRick = RickyKyle;
function App(props) {
  
  return (
  
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className='heading-1'>Never Miss A Birthday!</h1>
      <aside className='aside-1'>Here are the Birthday of some of my Favorite people!</aside>
    <Accordian />
    <span>
     <img src={gus} alt=''/>
    </span>
    <span>
    <img src={dadMatt} alt='dad ' />
    </span>
    <span>
    <img src={daveDaDon} alt=''/>
    </span>
    <span>
    <img src={profilePic} alt=''/>
    </span>
    <span>
    <img src={bigDickRick} alt=''/>
    </span>
    
    </div>
  );
}
```

ive tried require in the src attribute, and have named the files with const vars.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us a look at your error? What does it say?
Also in the 4th line of the code you paste, you forgot the "./"
Instead of this

```
import DavidDaDon from 'DavidDaDon.png';
```

it should be like this:

```
import DavidDaDon from './DavidDaDon.png';
```

Comment: ERROR in ./src/accordian.js 8:0-37
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Dad-Matt.png' in '/Users/ecwiegand/Desktop/ReactPractice/project-2/bday-reminder/src'
ERROR in ./src/accordian.js 9:0-40
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'DavidDaDon.png' in 
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories  If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.

Comment: so I am dumb.... I screwed up the imports on my accordion file! I fixed my own problem- shout out to my UX Designer gf